# IronPython code not working in 3.4 but worked in 2.7

Tags: python, c#, .net, syntax, ironpython

So I have installed IronPython 3.4 to replace the IronPython 2.7 I was using. The code below worked fine in 2.7 but when I use it in 3.4 I am getting the error: Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException: 'invalid syntax' Any ideas? Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine pythonEngine = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine();
            Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource pythonScript = pythonEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("print 'Hello World!'");
            pythonScript.Execute();

        }
    }
}
```

Tried the code above and it didn't work but worked in IronPython 2.7.

Comment: `print` is a function call in python3.

Comment: It worked in IronPython 2.7 though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`IronPython 3.4` uses python 3.4 syntax](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3/releases/tag/v3.4.0-beta1) where as `IronPython 2.7` uses python 2.7.

In python 2.7 `print` is a statement, where as in python 3 `print` is a function(which means you need to use parentheses to wrap the arguments). So to make your code work you have to change the following section from

```
pythonEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("print 'Hello World!'");
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

to

```
pythonEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("print('Hello World!')");
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Okay thanks. So is there anyway I could get this to run as I am new to python